# ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE error with prisma during Heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, prisma

first of all, thank you for your help!

I've been trying to deploy my backend app in node.js but everytime I do I'd run into the same issue and I don't know what is that? it was working fine until yesterday

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
   
-----> Creating runtime environment
   
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   NODE_MODULE_CACHE=false
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
   
   Resolving node version 14.x...
   Downloading and installing node 14.16.0...
   Using default npm version: 6.14.11
   
  -----> Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules
   
   > @prisma/client@2.16.1 postinstall /tmp/build_9659a05e/node_modules/@prisma/client
   > node scripts/postinstall.js
   
   warning In order to use "@prisma/client", please install Prisma CLI. You can install it with "npm add -D prisma".
   
   > avenidaz-node@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_9659a05e
   > npx prisma generate
   
   Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
   Error: 
   TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
       at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
       at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
       at Object.generateClient (/tmp/build_9659a05e/node_modules/@prisma/client/generator-build/index.js:72910:56)
       at async LineStream.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_9659a05e/node_modules/@prisma/client/generator-build/index.js:2802:26)
   
   
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! avenidaz-node@1.0.0 postinstall: `npx prisma generate`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the avenidaz-node@1.0.0 postinstall script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.WWuef/_logs/2021-04-06T03_48_25_103Z-debug.log
 -----> Build failed
   
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
   
  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
  !     Push failed
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my aoo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "back end of avenida z",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npx prisma generate",
  "start": "node src/server.js",
  "test": "mocha tests/**/*.js --exit"
},
"author": "owner",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"@prisma/client": "^2.16.1",
"@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.1",
"aws-sdk": "^2.768.0",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-oauth-server": "^2.0.0",
"heroku-ssl-redirect": "^0.1.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"multer": "^1.4.2",
"papaparse": "^5.3.0",
"pg": "^8.3.2",
"pgtools": "^0.3.0",
"sequelize": "^6.3.4",
"uuid": "^8.3.1",
"winston": "^3.3.3"
},
 "devDependencies": {
   "@prisma/cli": "^2.15.0",
   "mocha": "^8.3.0",
   "prisma": "^2.16.1"
 }
}
```

I already try taking out the carat on the prisma dependecies and even removing the prisma from the package.json and ran npm i

I've also tried reset the app by running repo:reset and re-deployed

I tried rolling back the previous commit but i still get the ran error

I noticed that when i run the console in heroku console to check the package.json (cat package.json), the package.json is not updated at all when i tried removing the carats or the prisma from the package.json,

Comment: Seems like Heroku is caching the dependencies. I would suggest including the latest and same version of `prisma` and `@prisma/client` in your `package.json` and then deploying so that `npx prisma generate` uses the local `prisma` binary.

Comment: @Ryan i already did that, still same error, when i run the heroku console and check the package.json, it looks the same like it didn't change despite I deployed the new changes